# PostgreSQL data from last day evening to morning

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with this structure and data

| Id | Data | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sample1 | 2022-11-10 | 21:10:00 |
| 2 | sample2 | 2022-11-10 | 23:50:00 |
| 3 | sample3 | 2022-11-11 | 01:20:00 |
| 4 | sample4 | 2022-11-11 | 05:30:00 |
| 5 | sample5 | 2022-11-11 | 20:59:00 |
| 6 | sample6 | 2022-11-11 | 23:01:00 |
| 7 | sample7 | 2022-11-12 | 01:01:00 |
| 8 | sample8 | 2022-11-12 | 04:01:00 |

.............................................
and so on

I want the structure in this way

| date | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-11 | 21:10:00 | 05:30:00 |
| 2022-11-12 | 20:59:00 | 04:01:00 |

The time is not fixed, so hard to figure out. One logic is to get the data after 7 pm to 8 am but not sure. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear to me why there should be a break between row 4 and 5. Find an algorithm that describes what you need, and you are halfway to the solution.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I believe that is the break between morning and evening per the title. So `05:30:00` is the last morning entry of the day and `20:59:00` is the first evening entry. That being said it not clear what the actual values are that mark the morning and evening breaks.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, there will not be any logic, so in some cases, there might be 2 rows of data and sometime might be 10 rows. That's why I want the first data after 7pm as the start time and may be the last data before 8am to be the end time

Comment: You want group the timestamp by `7 pm to next day 8 am'. `7 pm to next day8 am`  data in a group, and `next day 8 am to 7 pm` in another group.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

database structure

```
create table work (id serial, data text, ev_date date, ev_time time);
insert into work(data, ev_date, ev_time) values 
('sample1', '2022-11-10',   '21:10:00'),
('sample2', '2022-11-10',   '23:50:00'),
('sample3', '2022-11-11',   '01:20:00'),
('sample4', '2022-11-11',   '05:30:00'),
('sample5', '2022-11-11',   '20:59:00'),
('sample6', '2022-11-11',   '23:01:00'),
('sample7', '2022-11-12',   '01:01:00'),
('sample8', '2022-11-12',   '04:01:00');
```

query

the algorithm is as follows:

1. we group by date
2. we determine the interval -5 hours and + 8 hours
3. we look for the first time values depending on the order (-5 hours - the first larger value, +8 hours - the first smaller value)
4. removing the nulls

```
with s as (select ev_date from work group by ev_date),
     p as (select s.ev_date,
     (select work.ev_time from work 
        where (s.ev_date - interval '5 hour')::date = work.ev_date 
                and ((s.ev_date - interval '5 hour')::time < work.ev_time) 
        order by work.ev_date,work.ev_time limit 1) start_time,
     (select work.ev_time from work 
        where (s.ev_date + interval '8 hour')::date = work.ev_date 
                and ((s.ev_date + interval '8 hour')::time > work.ev_time) 
        order by work.ev_date,work.ev_time desc limit 1) end_time
     from s)
     select p.ev_date,p.start_time,p.end_time from p where p.start_time is not null and p.end_time is not null order by p.ev_date;
```

result

```
  ev_date   | start_time | end_time
------------+------------+----------
 2022-11-11 | 21:10:00   | 05:30:00
 2022-11-12 | 20:59:00   | 04:01:00
```